# how to fix this error when published in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

I encountered problem when deploying web system to server.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

before im using IIS 7 in my windows 7 laptop. it works..but when deploying to server(window server 2012 r2) using IIS 8.5.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>`enter code here`
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <!--<authentication mode="Windows"/>-->
    <!--<identity impersonate="false" />-->
    <authentication mode="Windows">
      <!--<forms name="ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="15" slidingExpiration="false" />-->
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADService" connectionUsername="smic.ithelpdesk" connectionPassword="H3lp8002" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
        <!--<add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 

type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADService" 

attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />-->
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <!-- <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>-->
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.1" newVersion="3.0.0.1"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
```

Comment: Did you mark the dependency "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" as copy local = true ?

Comment: @J.K yes, I already do that and still got this error.

Comment: Did you check that the dependency exists in the server? the same version as you have locally?

Comment: @J.K can you guide me how to check?what should i do? thanks

Comment: First, try to find where the dependency exists in your local machine. Usually, it will be inside a bin folder. Then, go to the IIS folder in the server, and you should find the same folder as you have locally. I guess you will not find the dependency there. You can copy/paste it manually and test. Also, check that the version is the same.

Comment: Hi @J.K, the program is now on live. we just install mvc3 and 4 in server.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

we just install asp.net mvc3 and mvc4 in server